# Get nearest location based on spatial coordinates

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation

I have a MySQL table full of places with latitudes/longitudes. And on the other side I have a client-side javascript/html5 page that sends coordinates to the server.

Using client's coordinates, I'd like to be able to locate nearest locations. What would be the simplest way of achieving this goal?

Something like `SELECT * FROM places AS p WHERE p.latitude NEAR '49.8330001' AND p.longitude NEAR '-119.45600';` would be really nice.

I encountered a few questions on here but they didn't gave me a proper answer. I read about MySQL's spatial extension and about a few other SQL queries that might do the trick but nothing seemed really "straightforward" so I thought there could be a more standardized way of doing it with some examples I could check out.

Anybody has experience with these?

Comment: how accurate should "near" be? barebones simplest method is to subtract the current location from the db locations and sort by smalelest difference, e.g. `select abs(latitude - $lat) AS lat, abs(longitude - $lon) AS $log ... order by lat desc, lon desc` type thing. no fancy math involved, just some subtraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following PHP code uses MySQL and [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to find nearest places coordinates to your point.

It creates a [**JSON**](http://www.json.org/) array of coordinates.

```
// Prepare statements
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  name, lat, lng,
           ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( lat ) )
           * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) 
           * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM table HAVING distance < ? 
           ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 20");
// Assign parameters
$stmt->bindParam(1,$center_lat);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$center_lng);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$center_lat);
$stmt->bindParam(4,$radius);
//Execute query
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
 $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
exit;
```

This [**Maps**](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/stationmap8a.php) markers are generated using this query

Answer (score 0):

You can use a quadkey. It's a spatial index based on a space filling curve. You can download my php class hilbert curve @ phpclasses.org.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you compute distance between the point you have and each coordinate in your database in an array. Then, you choose the min in this array.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you simply create a tolerance like 5% of the coordinate and then do a

```
$latplus5percent = $lat + .5*$lat; 
$latminus5percent = $lat - .5*$lat;
WHERE p.latitude BETWEEN $latplus5percent AND $latminus5percent
```

[edit: format]